# Changing attributes in different objects

Tags: python, object-oriented, tkinter

First some background - I am developing a Python program which has thousands of lines spread across many files. I have intermediate programming skills - and no commercial OOP experience, and have taught myself Python recently. I have come across a problem which I can solve, in a number of different ways, but I'm not really happy with any of my solutions - they don't feel quite right from an OOP point of view. I have tried to make things generic so they can be used for lots of different options, but by doing so it seems massively convoluted.

I have distilled the problem down into a comparatively small piece of code for review. I have a main object, and I have an object which holds some options (which are just true/false for now, but could be other things in the future). I then have a third object (a tkinter button) that each *show the status of the option (via being sunken or raised), and when clicked, change the value*.

I felt the right way to do this would be for the functionality (in italics above) to be contained entirely in the `toggleButton` class. At first I just passed it `self.options.Option1` (or whatever), but that didn't work. I then read up on does Python pass by value or reference, which (I know I am simplifying here) seemed to say that when you pass an object it passes the object, but when you pass something like an integer or boolean it passes the value. So I changed it to what you see now - where you pass the variable, an integer representing the variable, and changing the options class to have a function to change the option. It all seems so needlessly verbose. Is there a better way?

```
from Tkinter import *

class optionsClass():
    _OPTION1 = 1
    _OPTION2 = 2

    def __init__(self):
        self.Option1 = True
        self.Option2 = False

    def change(self, optionid):
        if optionid == optionsClass._OPTION1:
            if self.Option1 == True:
                self.Option1 = False
            else:
                self.Option1 = True
        if optionid == optionsClass._OPTION2:
            if self.Option2 == True:
                self.Option2 = False
            else:
                self.Option2 = True

class toggleButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, master, targetObject, targetoptionid, initialval
                    , **kwargs):
        Button.__init__(self, master, command = self.callback, **kwargs)
        self.targetoptionid = targetoptionid
        self.targetObject = targetObject
        if initialval==True:
            self.config(relief=SUNKEN)
        else:
            self.config(relief=RAISED)

    def callback(self):
        self.targetObject.change(self.targetoptionid)
        if self.cget("relief") == SUNKEN:
            self.config(relief=RAISED)
        else:
            self.config(relief=SUNKEN)


class mainframe(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.options = optionsClass()
        option1box = toggleButton(self, self.options, optionsClass._OPTION1,
                self.options.Option1, text="Option 1")
        option1box.grid(column=0, row=0)
        option2box = toggleButton(self, self.options, optionsClass._OPTION2,
                self.options.Option2, text="Option 2")
        option2box.grid(column=0, row=1)
        testbutton= Button(self, command = self.outputoptions,
                             text="Return option values")
        testbutton.grid(column=0, row=2)

    def outputoptions(self):
        print "Option 1 is " + str(self.options.Option1)
        print "Option 2 is " + str(self.options.Option2)


top = Tk()
m = mainframe(top)
m.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Things to bear in mind...

- I would like the options class to work for things other than boolean without much difficulty.
- I like the convenience and readability of the main class to simply say `self.options.Option1`.
- Ideally there will still be three classes, as mainframe and option do a lot more in the actual program, and `toggleButton` is used multiple times and is therefore a good candidate to be a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to answer your question on passing by value/reference, Python *doesn't* pass mutable (e.g. `list`, `dict`) and immutable (e.g. `str`, `tuple`) objects any differently - the difference appears *because* they are[n't] mutable, i.e. can[not] be changed in-place. *Names in Python are just references to objects.*

When you pass an immutable object:

```
def calling():
    foo = "bar" # bind str object to name 'foo' in scope of 'calling'
    called(foo) # pass reference to str object to 'called'
    print(foo) # still "bar"

def called(baz): # first arg object will be bound to name 'baz' in scope of 'called'
    baz = "{0}!".format(baz) # rebinds name 'baz' to **new str object**
    print(baz)
```

In this case, the string is immutable, it can't be changed in-place, so changes in `called` won't be reflected in `calling`, as `calling` still references the original object.

By contrast, with a mutable type:

```
def calling():
    foo = [] # bind list object to name 'foo' in scope of calling function
    called(foo) # pass reference to list object to 'called'
    print(foo) # see change from 'called'

def called(baz): # first arg object will be bound to name 'baz' in scope of 'called'
    baz.append("hello, world") # object bound to name 'baz' (and 'foo') **is changed**
    print(baz)
```

---

You should read and consider following the [Python Style Guide, PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - class names should be `CapitalizedWords` and variable, function and method names should be `lowercase_with_underscores`.

---

`optionsClass` can be streamlined. At the very least, note that

```
if self.Option1 == True:
    self.Option1 = False
else:
    self.Option1 = True
```

can be simplified to:

```
self.Option1 = not self.Option1
```

Dictionaries would allow you to simplify further:

```
class OptionsClass():

    id_map = {'Option1': 1, 'Option2': 2}

    def __init__(self, options=None):
        if options is None:
            options = {1: True, 2: False}
        self.options = options

    def change(self, option_id):
        self.options[option_id] = not self.options[option_id]

    def __getattr__(self, attr_name):
        return self.options[id_map[attr_name]]
```

Now you can use it:

```
>>> o = OptionsClass()
>>> o.Option1
True
>>> o.Option2
False
>>> o.change(1)
>>> o.Option1
False
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't gotten fully used to the ideas of dicts yet, great chance to practice the use of it here so thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[@jonrsharpe](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/32391/jonrsharpe) did most of the heavy lifting on this answer. I'll just point out a couple things that can be improved:

1. In the statement `if self.Option1 == True`, the `== True` part is not needed. Since `self.Option1` holds a boolean value, you can simply use its value to satisfy the if's conditional.

   ---

   As a side-note, you can actually use non-boolean values as the conditional in an if-statement because Python treats empty iterables as `False`. So:

   ```
   foo = []
   bar = {}
   baz = ''

   if not foo and not bar and not baz:
       print('They all were considered False')
   else:
       print('Guess I was wrong...')
   ```
2. Don't use `from MyModule import *` unless you *really* are using **everything** from that module. If you aren't using everything, then the star-import can bring a lot of unnecessary fluff into your program.

   A general rule-of-thumb is to be as specific as prudent.

   Example: say I use a **lot** of `QWidget`s from `PySide.QtGui`. I'm not going to import them all:

   ```
   from Pyside.QtGui import QTableWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, etc...
   ```

   because, odds are, I'll will eventually need another `QWidget` (or stop using one). This clutters up the top of the file and can make it hard to maintain. Instead, I would simply use the import statement:

   ```
    from PySide import QtGui
   ```

   and append the `QtGui` namespace to all of my `QWidget` declarations.
3. As Jon's answer pointed out, take a look at [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines). It will help your code look and feel more Pythonic. Currently your code is quite good. However, there are a few nitpick-ey things I could find:

   - Don't put spaces before and after the `=` sign for keyword arguments.
   - Use a single blank line to separate logical sections of code. This can help your `mainFrame`'s `__init__` function look better.
   - Use 2 blank lines between `class` declarations.

Comment: Using var == True or simply using var... I knew about this but 1) I find the former more readable, and 2) the code I am basing it on uses == True, so I stuck with it. :) About importing... I am indeed using an absolute ton of widgets... does the benefit of only importing some outweigh the convenience/readability of my code? And thanks I will read PEP8 and try to abide by it - I want to put this code on github eventually so I want it to be as Pythonic as possible.